# Does Ruby's regular expression comply with standard?

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to match the following string, basically for crontab.

```
0 2 * * 0,1,2,3,4,5,6
```

which is "0 2 * *" followed by at most 7 numbers from 0 to 6 (i.e., seven days of week) separated by comma. Below is what I got from ruby.

```
$ irb
irb> /0 2 \* \* [0-6]((,[0-6]){0,6})/ =~ "0 2 * * 1,2"
=> 0
irb> /0 2 \* \* [0-6]((,[0-6]){0,6})/ =~ "0 2 * * 7"
=> nil
irb> /0 2 \* \* [0-6]((,[0-6]){0,6})/ =~ "0 2 * * 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7"
=> 0
```

For the last one, why it still matches?

Then I test the same regular expression using http://regexpal.com/. It works as expected, which indicates my regular expression is correct.

Comment: Why would it not match?

Comment: Which "standard"? There's a bunch of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your regular expression is not anchored, it will match any string that contains it, even if the string has extra characters before or after the pattern.

Change this:

```
/0 2 \* \* [0-6]((,[0-6]){0,6})/
```

to this:

```
/^0 2 \* \* [0-6]((,[0-6]){0,6})$/
```

And it will work as you expect.  `^` anchors to the beginning of a line; `$` to the end.

When you try the last regex and string on http://regexpal.com, you may notice that the portion of the string that matches is highlighted:

> > **0 2 * * 0,1,2,3,4,5,6**,7

Only the portion that is highlighted matched.  This shows you that regexpal and Ruby are doing the same thing, in this case.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But can you explain why it matches with the wrong string? Because even you don't anchor, it shouldn't match. It seems crappy.

Comment: @user180574 Did you expect the last string to not match because it has a 7?  The 7 doesn't matter, because the regex matched before it got to the 7.  The regex engine never even looked at the `,7` at the end.

Comment: Thanks, I have some misunderstanding, now it's clear.

Comment: @user180574 Glad to help.  By the way, it seems like you're a solid member of the community--have you thought of converting your account to a real account so that you can select a username?